# Fluorescence solvated band shape in Gaussian16

Tags: gaussian

I am trying to calculate the fluorescence spectra **in solvent** with Gaussian16. I followed the example reported [here](https://gaussian.com/scrf/) to calculate the value of the vertical emission. However, in the same link, I read:
*For the solvated band shape, one must do Freq=(ReadFC,FC,Emission,ReadFCHT) using the checkpoint files for steps 1 and 5, but also providing the state-specific emission energy in the input section for the Franck-Condon calculation.*

I have calculated the steps 1 and 5, but I don't know (and I don't find much in the manual) how to include the energy in the input section of the FC calculation. Does someone have any idea of the input keyword to use? Thanks!

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago but have you figured this out now? Please update us! Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer?

Comment: Dear Nike, unfortunately I didn't have any answer about this. I would be glad to have an answer, still